# How to create optional parameters using object array

Tags: c#

I am creating a method which MUST be use with or without parameters.
I am using object array so that I can hold string, integer, binary types, etc at the same time.

**Method:**
SQLDB_UsingReader(string strSQL_WithParam, params object[,] obj)

**Error:**
The array must be a single dimensional array.

**P.S**
This method **SQLDB_UsingReader(string strSQL_WithParam, object[,] obj)** is working, but when I add "**params**" as the solution I searched when creating optional parameter, the error occurs.

**CODE**

```
public void SQLDB_UsingReader(string strSQL_WithParam, params object[,] obj)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlCommand mCmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL_WithParam, mConn))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < obj.Length / 2; i++)
                {
                    if (obj[i, 1] == null || obj[i, 1].ToString() == "" || obj[i, 1].ToString().Length == 0)
                    { mCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(obj[i, 0].ToString(), DBNull.Value)); }
                    else
                    { mCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(obj[i, 0].ToString(), obj[i, 1])); }
                }
                mConn.Open();
                mDataReader = mCmd.ExecuteReader();
                mConn.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { ex.ToString(); }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide examples of how you are expecting to invoke your method, if you could make it work?

Comment: @sstan : I may use that as SQLDB_UsingReader("select * from table") or SQLDB_UsingReader("select * from table where id=@ID",obj) Where obj has "Parameter_Name","Parameter_Value"

Answer (score 0):

Use `Dictionary<string, object>`. You have two values: a string and an object per parameter you wish to set. Either create a class that has one of each and use params for an array of that class or simply use the built in type for a collection of named values.

```
public void SQLDB_UsingReader(string strSQL_WithParam, IDictionary<string, object> obj)
{
    try
    {
        string where = obj.Any() ? ("where " + string.Join("AND", obj
                                   .Select(x => x.Key +"==@" + x.Key)) : "";
        using (SqlCommand mCmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL_WithParam + where, mConn))
        {
            foreach pair in obj
            {
                ... (use pair.Value and pair.Key)
            }
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I tried this, but how can I make it to be OPTIONAL parameters.

I may use that as:
x.SQLDB_UsingReader("select * from table") or x.SQLDB_UsingReader("select * from table where id=@ID",Dictionary)

Where Dictionary has "Parameter_Name","Parameter_Value"

Comment: You could build the where clause as a string in parallel by aggregating the parameter names. `string.Join("AND", obj.Select(x => x.Key +"==@" + x.Key)` assuming each key is a column name. You'd still need to check for nothing in the dictionary and thus no `where` clause to add.